# CoronaSDK upload data file to application

Tags: android, ios, coronasdk

Is it possible to import and export assets to and from Corona application? For example I have data file which I can export and than import again in another application? For backup or sync purposes. 
Can it be done via http server? Like in many applications I get an address 10.0.0.1:8080 connect to it via regular browser and than can perform upload/downloads.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you should be able to easily with the `network.request` API.  It's very versatile.

http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/library/network/request.html